# Unknown prepared statement handler (0) given to mysql_stmt_execute in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I've written some PHP code to insert some data into a MySQL table using the mysqli extension and prepared statements. The MySQL server is running version 5.0.77.

I tested the code locally on my machine running version 5.5.27 and it runs perfectly fine. When I transfer my code to the server with the older version of MySQL, I get the error "**Unknown prepared statement handler (0) given to mysql_stmt_execute" each time**".

I've googled for this error a lot and only found bug reports which all seem to have been fixed before version 5.0.77. The other strange thing is that the reports sometime mention the number in error message changing, while in my case, the number remains constant at 0, regardless of how many different browsers I simultaneously open a connection from.

I can't upgrade the server, since it is not under my control, and serves a lot of other users as well.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be happening, or how to fix it? Thank you very much.

**Edit**

The PHP code is pasted at http://pastebin.com/1X4f5G5Z. I've added some comments that should help understand what the functions do.

I am using wrapper classes over the mysqli extention as provided at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#110363

Comment: I've added a lot of error checking throught the mysqli code, and everything is working fine right up to the point I execute the prepared statement.

Comment: How about showing your code?

Comment: It's an older version.....try using mysql extension instead of mysqli....tell me what happen ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've added some links to the code. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things without any success. This is possibly a bug in MySQL v5.0.77.

I finally got my code to work by resorting to the workaround by @robert-rozas in the comments and migrating my code to mysqli extension, and now it works great! Reposting here to resolve the question.