# Multiple rows from same table to single row with like identifier

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-columns

I am new to SQL queries and am trying to compact a number of rows down to a single row with a like identifier. Below is an example:

```
Table orders:

groupid | question   | answer

|-----------------------------------|

abc000  | First Name | John 

abc000  | Last Name  | Doe

abc000  | City       | Denver

...     | ...        | ...

abc000  | Entry      | Individual

abc000  | Shirt Size | X-Large

abc001  | First Name | Jane

abc001  | Last Name  | Doe

abc001  | City       | Seattle

...     | ...        | ...

abc001  | Entry      | Individual

(No Shirt entry)
```

I am trying to get it to look like:

Table confirmations(desired output):

groupid | Last Name | First Name | City | ... | Shirt Size

|----------------------------------------------------------|

abc000 | Doe | John | Denver | ... | X-Large

abc001 | Doe | Jane | Seattle | ... | Small

Table confirmations(actual output):

groupid | Last Name | First Name | City | ... | Shirt Size

|----------------------------------------------------------|

abc000 | Doe | John | Denver | ... |

abc000 | Doe | John | Denver | ... | X-Large

abc001 | Doe | Jane | Seattle | ... |

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT om.groupid, om.fid, om.eid, f.subtitle,
        IF(oi.question = 'First Name', oi.answer, '') AS fname,
        IF(oi1.question = 'Last Name', oi1.answer, '') AS lname,
        IF(oi2.question = 'City', oi2.answer, '') AS city,
        IF(oi3.question = 'State', oi3.answer, '') AS state,
        IF(oi4.question = 'Birthdate', oi4.answer, '') AS bday,
        IF(oi5.question = 'Gender', oi5.answer, '') AS gender,
        IF ( (oi6.question LIKE '%fee'), oi6.answer, '') as event,
        IF ( (oi7.question = 'shirt size (unisex cotton)'), oi7.answer, '') as shirt
    FROM ordermeta om
    JOIN orders o ON o.orderid=om.orderid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON oi.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi1 ON oi1.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi2 ON oi2.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi3 ON oi3.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi4 ON oi4.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi5 ON oi5.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi6 ON oi6.groupid=om.groupid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi7 ON oi7.groupid=om.groupid
    WHERE  oi.question = 'First NAME'
        AND oi1.question = 'Last Name'
        AND oi2.question = 'City'
        AND oi3.question = 'State'
        AND oi4.question = 'Birthdate'
        AND oi5.question = 'Gender'
        AND oi6.question LIKE '%fee%'
    ORDER BY lname ASC
```

If I remove Shirt Size, it works perfectly. I have added:

```
AND oi7.question = "Shirt Size"
```

except that it may not always be "Shirt Size", but more LIKE "%shirt size%" and when there isn't a question that = shirt size, I want it to leave a null or blank space. With the AND, it will only give me results that also have shirt questions. (55 of 140 results)

The current code, I get two entries when question = "shirt size" exists (one is blank the other has good information). All other entries have a single entry with no information. (195 of 140 results)

I have tried multiple different things like CASE, IF THEN statements. All of them do the same where it works great until I add the shirt question.

Please, let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

An example of one of the SE types I have tried:
[Combine multiple rows into one row MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118809/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I found that there were two questions that had "shirt". This was creating a second entry that fit the model to leave a second row with a blank since it didn't fit the second filter from the select. Here is what I eventually had to write.

```
SELECT DISTINCT om.groupid, om.fid, om.eid, f.subtitle,
        IF(oi.question = 'First Name', oi.answer, '') AS fname,
        IF(oi1.question = 'Last Name', oi1.answer, '') AS lname,
        IF(oi2.question = 'City', oi2.answer, '') AS city,
        IF(oi3.question = 'State', oi3.answer, '') AS state,
        IF(oi4.question = 'Birthdate', oi4.answer, '') AS bday,
        IF(oi5.question = 'Gender', oi5.answer, '') AS gender,
        IF ( (oi6.question LIKE '%fee'), oi6.answer, '') as event,
        IF ( (oi7.question IN ('Youth Shirts','Event Shirt','Tech Shirt Size','Series Shirt','Choose Event Shirt(s)','Shirt Size (Included in Entry)','Regular T-Shirt OR Tech Shirt - Select Size/Type','shirt size (unisex cotton)')), oi7.answer, '') as shirt
    FROM ordermeta om
    JOIN orders o ON o.orderid=om.orderid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON oi.groupid=om.groupid AND oi.question = 'First Name'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi1 ON oi1.groupid=om.groupid AND oi1.question = 'Last Name'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi2 ON oi2.groupid=om.groupid AND oi2.question = 'City'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi3 ON oi3.groupid=om.groupid AND oi3.question = 'State'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi4 ON oi4.groupid=om.groupid AND oi4.question = 'Birthdate'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi5 ON oi5.groupid=om.groupid AND oi5.question = 'Gender'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi6 ON oi6.groupid=om.groupid AND oi6.question LIKE '%fee%'
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi7 ON oi7.groupid=om.groupid AND oi7.question IN ('Youth Shirts','Event Shirt','Tech Shirt Size','Series Shirt','Choose Event Shirt(s)','Shirt Size (Included in Entry)','Regular T-Shirt OR Tech Shirt - Select Size/Type','shirt size (unisex cotton)')
    LEFT JOIN forms f ON f.fid=om.fid
    WHERE om.status = 1
        AND o.paid = 1
        AND f.fid=$fid
    ORDER BY lname ASC
```

It is an extremely ugly bit since the shirts size entries are flexible... Will need to standardize the entry to make the query only look for LIKE "shirt size%"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  om.groupid, 
        om.fid, 
        om.eid, 
        f.subtitle,
        IF(oi.question = 'First Name', oi.answer, '') AS fname,
        IF(oi1.question = 'Last Name', oi1.answer, '') AS lname,
        IF(oi2.question = 'City', oi2.answer, '') AS city,
        IF(oi3.question = 'State', oi3.answer, '') AS state,
        IF(oi4.question = 'Birthdate', oi4.answer, '') AS bday,
        IF(oi5.question = 'Gender', oi5.answer, '') AS gender,
        IF ( (oi6.question LIKE '%fee'), oi6.answer, '') as event,
        IF ( (oi7.question = 'shirt size (unisex cotton)'), oi7.answer, '') as shirt
    FROM ordermeta om
    JOIN orders o ON o.orderid=om.orderid
    LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON oi.groupid=om.groupid
    WHERE   oi.question IN( 'First NAME','Last Name','City','State','Birthdate','Gender')
        OR oi.question LIKE  '%fee%'
GROUP BY om.groupid, 
        om.fid, 
        om.eid, 
        f.subtitle,
        IF(oi.question = 'First Name', oi.answer, '') AS fname,
        IF(oi1.question = 'Last Name', oi1.answer, '') AS lname,
        IF(oi2.question = 'City', oi2.answer, '') AS city,
        IF(oi3.question = 'State', oi3.answer, '') AS state,
        IF(oi4.question = 'Birthdate', oi4.answer, '') AS bday,
        IF(oi5.question = 'Gender', oi5.answer, '') AS gender,
        IF ( (oi6.question LIKE '%fee'), oi6.answer, '') as event,
        IF ( (oi7.question = 'shirt size (unisex cotton)'), oi7.answer, '') as shirt
    ORDER BY lname ASC
```