# MySQL: combine 2 rows from another table into a single result row

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

These are fake table names but in my actual problem, imagine a business rule stating that every parent has either 1 or 2 children. These children have a number of either 0 or 1. two children of the same parent cannot have the same number.

I want access to fields in the rows of `children` but want there values placed into a number prefixed field. Example:

parenttochildrenassoc:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|    parent   |    child    |
+-------------+-------------+
|      1      |      1      |
|      1      |      2      |
|      2      |      3      |
|      3      |      4      |
+-------------+-------------+
```

children:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|    child    |    number   |    name    |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|      1      |      0      |   Chuck    |
|      2      |      1      |   Sally    |
|      3      |      0      |   Carly    |
|      4      |      1      |   Billy    |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

desired result:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   parent    |    child0   |   child1   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|      1      |    Chuck    |    Sally   |
|      2      |    Carly    |     NULL   |
|      3      |     NULL    |    Billy   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Closest I could get is below:

```
SELECT A.parent, C0.name as child0, C1.name as child1
FROM parenttochildassoc A
    LEFT JOIN children C0 ON C0.child = A.child AND C0.number = 0
    LEFT JOIN children C1 ON C1.child = A.child AND C1.number = 1
```

which produces this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   parent    |    child0   |   child1   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|      1      |    Chuck    |     NULL   |
|      1      |     NULL    |    Sally   |
|      2      |    Carly    |     NULL   |
|      3      |     NULL    |    Billy   |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

How can I flatten this? It seems very similar to the "pivot" described in in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118989/1800023), (one of the proposed answers is identical to my attempt) but the fact that `parenttochildrenassoc` is many to one appears to break it.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of children per parent?

Comment: 1 or 2 children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this with conditional aggregation and just one join:

```
SELECT a.parent,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.number = 0 THEN c.name END) as child0,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.number = 1 THEN c.name END) as child1
FROM parenttochildassoc a LEFT JOIN
     children c
     ON C0.child = A.child
GROUP BY a.parent;
```

You can readily expand this to any number of children you want.

If you can live with all the children in one field, then use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT a.parent,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.name ORDER BY c.number) as children
FROM parenttochildassoc a LEFT JOIN
     children c
     ON C0.child = A.child
GROUP BY a.parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a grouping on the `parent` column to collapse similar parent rows:

```
SELECT A.parent,
       MAX(C0.name) AS child0,
       MAX(C1.name) AS child1
FROM parenttochildassoc A
LEFT JOIN children C0
    ON C0.child = A.child AND C0.number = 0
LEFT JOIN children C1
    ON C1.child = A.child AND C1.number = 1
GROUP BY A.parent
```

The reason this should work is that the `MAX()` function ignores `NULL` values.  Hence, when the two rows with `parent` = 1 are being aggregated, only the non `NULL` value will appear in the result set.

Comment: will this work if I need to access additional fields in `children`? Could I just take the max of those as well?

Comment: Yes, you can just add additional fields, but you should look at Gordon's answer because it is slightly more straightforward.