# Combine multiple rows of three tables into one row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I read the question [Combine multiple rows into one row MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118809/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row-mysql) that shows how to make out of several rows of a *SELECT* statement a result with a single line. The [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37c03/2) also runs fine. In that question, there are two tables: *t1* and *t2*. My problem has three tables, which I have simplified for this question:

Table *languages*:

```
ID              INT(11)         NOT NULL    PRIMARY_KEY
name            VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL    UNIQUE
```

Table *languages_have_persons*:

```
Languages_ID    INT(11)         NOT NULL    PRIMARY_KEY
Persons_ID  INT(11)             NOT NULL
```

Table *persons*:

```
ID              INT(11)         NOT NULL    PRIMARY_KEY
firstName       VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
lastName        VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
```

What I want to do is to combine these tables similarly, but I fail to do so for several hours now. Here is my last try:

```
SELECT p1.ID
    , p1.firstName
    , p1.lastName
    CONCAT_WS(', '
        , l2de.name
        , l2en.name
    )
    FROM
        languages_have_persons AS lp, persons AS p1
    LEFT JOIN languages AS l2de ON
        l2de.ID = 4 -- German
    LEFT JOIN languages AS l2en ON
        l2en.ID = 5 -- English
WHERE p1.ID = lp.Persons_ID
ORDER BY lastName, firstName;
```

The error message reads:

```
Fehler
SQL-Befehl: Dokumentation


SELECT p1.ID AS ID
    , p1.firstName AS firstName
    , p1.lastName AS lastName
    CONCAT_WS(', '
        , l2de.name
        , l2en.name
    )
    FROM
        languages_have_persons AS lp, persons AS p1
    LEFT JOIN languages AS l2de ON
        l2de.ID = 4     LEFT JOIN languages AS l2en ON
        l2en.ID = 5 WHERE p1.ID = lp.Persons_ID
ORDER BY lastName, firstName LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL meldet: Dokumentation

#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch
nachschlagen bei '(', '
        , l2de.name
        , l2en.name
    )
    FROM
        languages_have_persons AS lp, ' in Zeile 4
```

I also tried other ways, but none had the correct syntax. What I want as result is as follows:

Table *language*:

```
ID    name
4     German
5     English
```

Table *language_have_persons*:

```
Languages_ID    Persons_ID    
    4                2
    5                1
    5                2
```

Table *persons*:

```
ID    firstName    lastName
1     Joe           Frazier
2     Arnold        Schwarzenegger
```

What I expect from the correct SELECT statement is something like

```
firstName    lastName           CONCAT_WS(…
Joe           Frazier           English
Arnold        Schwarzenegger    German, English
```

Do you see the error in the SQL syntax above? If not, do you know how to solve it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You must add a comma before `CONCAT_WS`.

Comment: Thank you! That was it, but I couldn't see it & tried a lot of wrong statements.

Comment: The whole point of formatting queries this way is precisely to avoid that kind of error - so well done!!!

Comment: I'm not a fan of seeing mixed notation in the from  LEFT Join and comma notation.  I'm surprised the engine even allows that syntax to compile as it uses two different standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p1.ID
    , p1.firstName
    , p1.lastName,<--------------------I had made change at this line
    CONCAT_WS(', '
        , l2de.name
        , l2en.name
    )
    FROM
        languages_have_persons AS lp, persons AS p1
    LEFT JOIN languages AS l2de ON
        l2de.ID = 4 -- German
    LEFT JOIN languages AS l2en ON
        l2en.ID = 5 -- English
WHERE p1.ID = lp.Persons_ID
ORDER BY lastName, firstName;
```

Or, for your further query you can try below.

```
SELECT p1.ID
    , p1.firstName
    , p1.lastName,
    l2de.name
    FROM
    persons p1
    INNER JOIN languages_have_persons lp on p1.ID=lp.Persons_ID 
    INNER JOIN language l2de on l2de.ID=lp.Languages_ID 
    WHERE l2de.ID  IN(4,5)
    ORDER BY lastName, firstName;
```

You can try above query.

Comment: Thank you very much that you helped A BLIND MAAAN! ;-D

Comment: There is one more issue. I get all the languages for all persons, but I would see only those languages per row that this person really knows. Currently, the query returns for all persons 'German, English' even if they do not know German.

Comment: @Sae1962 You can try `INNER JOIN` on `persons.ID=language_have_persons.Persons_ID 
INNER JOIN ON language_have_persons.Languages_ID =languages.ID`

Comment: @SagarGanwal I replaced the WHERE clause above with "INNER JOIN ON persons.ID = language_have_persons.Persons_ID
INNER JOIN ON language_have_persons.Languages_ID = languages.ID", but got an error: …
INNER JOIN ON language_have_persons.Languages_ID = languages.ID
ORDER BY lastName, firstName LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL meldet: Dokumentation

#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei 'ON persons.ID = language_have_persons.Persons_ID
INNER JOIN ON language_have_pe' in Zeile 12

Comment: Also, my SELECT statement needs a DISTINCT. Otherwise, the rows are doubled, which also shows that some clause is missing (DISTINCT is not a good practice in such a case, I suppose).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148911/discussion-between-sae1962-and-sagar-gangwal).

Comment: @Sae1962 To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

On another site, I had another discussion, where the colleague found the solution, which is

```
SELECT DISTINCT pl.ID
    , firstName
    , lastName
    , languages
FROM persons p
    , ( SELECT
        lp.Persons_ID AS ID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.name) AS languages
    FROM languages l
        , languages_have_persons lp
    WHERE l.id = lp.Languages_ID
    GROUP BY lp.Persons_ID
    ) AS pl
WHERE p.id = pl.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```

So, the question is ANSWERED PROPERLY.