# SQL Output two rows into one row

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want SQL to outpot the rows rows given into one row:

SQL-Code:

```
SELECT medium.MediumID, Vorname, Zuname, Titel, medium.MediumID, medium.KategorieID, kategorie.Bezeichnung, Kurzbeschreibung, Umfang, Erscheinungsjahr
FROM autor INNER JOIN
     mediumautor
     ON mediumautor.AutorID = autor.AutorID INNER JOIN
     medium
     ON mediumautor.MediumID = medium.MediumID INNER JOIN
     kategorie
     ON medium.KategorieID = kategorie.KategorieID
WHERE medium.MediumID = 2552
GROUP BY mediumautor.AutorID
```

This is the Output:

[image: Picture of row-Output]

I appreciated your help very much!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please go read [ask]. Then edit your question, and make it include a proper, verbal explanation, of what you have, and what result exactly you want to achieve based on that.

Comment: `GROUP BY mediumautor.AutorID,mediumautor.MediumID`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine multiple rows into one row MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118809/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row-mysql)